# iphone iOS mapkit, filter a list of points(Longitude, Latitude) by Nearest

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I have a list of **points** of interest in a plist file containing **point info + longitude & latitude.**

I wonder how to **show** in a MapView the **nearest** points to me according to a **radius** ?

example : radius = 2km --> show the top 20 nearest pins to my location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the distance between your position and the points then sort and filter the results.

To calculate the distance use [distanceFromLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW18)

Comment: And notice that if you've enabled user location tracking then you can get the current user location as a CLLocation from mapView.userLocation.location, and key-value observe that to watch for changes. Pretty much the same question is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223147